# suggestion to prove a consequence of uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

*Prove that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on a set $E$, then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on every subset of $E$.*

Since $f_{n}\to f$ uniformly on a set $E$, let $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N\in \mathbb{N}$, such that if $n\geq N$ implies that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$, for all $x\in E$,
I have thought of considering a subsequence of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $X \subseteq E$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. We want to find an $N$ so that $|f_n x - f x| < \varepsilon$ for each $x \in X$ provided we make $n > N$.

But we *know* that we can find such an $N$ that works for all of $E$, since we're assuming $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$.

If we use the same choice of $N$, can you show that it works for $X$ as well? Keep in mind each $x \in X$ is *also* in $E$, since $X \subseteq E$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, @HallaSurvivor, I want that the same $N$ serves for $X$, 
but I'm not sure how to justify it

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to HallaSurvivor's answer:

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and let $A\subseteq E$. Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, we have:
$$\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$
Then for all $n\geq N$, we also have:
$$\sup_{x\in A}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon,$$
so $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $A$ as well.